# Facebox popup + asp.net button postback issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, facebox

i have a aspx page which i am loading using [facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/). In the form i have a button which submits the form.on clicking the button the facebox closes and browser shows the same form which was opened in facebok.

I used asp.net update panel to avoid  full postback in popup, but using update panel not showing the facebox popup.

how can i make the facebox popup windows stayed there as it was before postback.

Answer (score 0):

How is the facebox code being bound to the button? Now that the button is wrapped in an update panel, you may have to wait until after the update panel loads to bind.

You can put your js code in this event, and it will run each time an update panel ajax call finishes.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindButton())
```

Comment: update panel is in page which opens in facebbox popup. The page which open the facebox popup is simple aspx page with button in it on click of which facebox popup is opened.

Comment: Sorry, is the problem that facebox is not popping up, or not closing?

Comment: Popup is opened successfully, popup page displayed, clicked on button in popup, post back event fired. here comes the problem. popup hides after postback and the page which was opened in popup in now showing in browser instead of the page whcih opened the popup.

Comment: I've had a similar issue using jQuery UI Dialog before. Basically when the dialog is created, the <form> is moved and it messes with the update panel and the postback. Take a look here see if it makes any sense http://blog.roonga.com.au/2009/07/using-jquery-ui-dialog-with-aspnet-and.html